# H. pylori-caused Bad Breath: how does it smell like?

Tags: halitosis-bad-breath, helicobacter-pylori

One of my relatives has bad breath. Common causes, including dry oral cavity, poor dental health, dirty tongue coating, tonsil stones, are ruled out. We now suspect that H. pylori is the culprit.

He experiences stomachache sometimes, and is going to have a H. pylori breath test. Also, saliva samples taken nearer to oesophagus have a stronger smell, suggesting certain relation to stomach/lungs problems.

However, even the test result is positive, H. pylori might not be the actual cause. It is well known that (in our city) nearly one third of the population is infected by this bacteria, but often no symptoms can be observed.

So, I want to make a primary test before seeking advice from professionals.

> How does H. pylori-caused halitosis smell like? (please be descriptive and use simile)

Some Google results suggest that the breath smells like volatile sulphur compound. However this is strongly disagreed by some articles. A few articles suggested a smell of urine, but did not give any evidence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made an attempt to find the answer to this? It's readily available with a google search, which means the question isn't a good fit for the site. At least some degree of prior research is required here.

Comment: @CareyGregory I did a search but nothing comes up. What keywords did you search?

Comment: @CareyGregory I believe that you searched 'halitosis', 'H. pylori', 'smell' on Google and saw many cited articles, and thus concluded that an answer is readily available. I should emphasize that, most articles do not even describe the smell; some articles may suggest a relation to VSC, whose smell is well known, however this relation is disagreed by many other articles. Clearly, this question fits this site. Please delete your comment. If you downvoted, please undo the vote. As an active SE user for more than a year, I don't think that your comment meets the requirements of a moderator.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. I simply asked you what research you've done. That's a requirement here, so it's a reasonable question. Your comment above seems to indicate you've done some, so show it to us. Show us what you found and why it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @CareyGregory I am going to add a paragraph to the question about this. However, you said ‘(an answer) is readily available with a google search’, which is clearly false. You as a moderator, please seriously consider deleting your first comment, to avoid misleading other users to downvote.

Comment: To add to Carey's comment, for [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions so we ask to help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research.  I see you have done this which is great.

Comment: We also have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.

Comment: @Szeto, I strongly suggest to include the links to the sources that say: "However this is strongly disagreed by some articles." It can really help if we know who exactly says what exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SUMMARY:**

1. Individuals with H. pylori infection of the stomach can have increased amounts of the following **substances** in the breath:

   - Sulfides: hydrogen sulfide ([rotten eggs smell](https://www.osha.gov/OshDoc/data_Hurricane_Facts/hydrogen_sulfide_fact.pdf)), dimethyl sulfide ([cabbage-like smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethyl_sulfide)), methyl mercaptane ([rotten cabbage smell](https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/MHMI/mmg139.pdf))
   - Isobutane ([petroleum-like odor](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/isobutane)), 2-butanone ([pungent sweet odor](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/2-Butanone#section=Computed-Properties)) and ethyl acetate ([fruity odor](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/ethyl_acetate#section=Top))
   - Hydrogen nitrate ([choking odor](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/nitric_acid#section=Color)) and nitric oxide ([sharp sweet-smelling](https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/toxfaqs/tfacts175.pdf))
   - Hydrogen cyanide ([bitter almonds smell](https://emergency.cdc.gov/agent/cyanide/basics/facts.asp))
2. The **variety** of the substances comes from different ***strains*** of H. pylori in different individuals and, I assume, from different foods consumed.
3. According to [this 2005 review (Table 3)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3719490/), **hydrogen nitrate** with choking odor seems to be most specific, but not likely diagnostic, for H. pylori. Isobutane, 2-butanone and ethyl acetate smell like ketones in a low-carb diet or uncontrolled diabetes. Sulfide and cyanide smell can appear in various other infections.
4. The mentioned breath odors are **not anatomic-specific** and may arise not only from the stomach (H. pylori) but also from the mouth (parodontosis), throat (tonsil stones), or lungs (atelectasis).
5. Symptoms, like **upper abdominal bloating and excessive belching after meals,** can help in diagnosis of H. pylori.

---

**EVIDENCE:**

[Gastrointestinal diseases and halitosis: association of gastric Helicobacter pylori infection (PUbMed, 2002)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12090454/):

> The levels of **hydrogen sulphide** and **dimethyl sulphide** in mouth
>   air were also significantly higher in the [H pylori] positive
>   patients...

[Determination of volatile organic compounds in human breath for Helicobacter pylori detection by SPME-GC/MS (PubMed, 2011)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21321973):

> **isobutane, 2-butanone** and **ethyl acetate** were detected in the breath of persons with H. pylori in the stomach...

[H. pylori infection increases levels of exhaled nitrate (PubMed, 2005)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16181348/):

> ...in H. pylori-infected patients, levels of exhaled **hydrogen
>   nitrate** and **hydrogen cyanide** are found to be significantly
>   elevated.

[Clinical Application of Volatile Organic Compound Analysis for Detecting Infectious Diseases (PUbMed, 2013)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3719490/):

This review again mentions **isobutane, 2-butanone, ethyl acetate, HCN** and **hydrogen nitrate** in the breath of H pylori infected patients, but HCN is also detectable in exhaled-breath samples of P. aeruginosa-infected individuals.

[DOES HELICOBACTER PYLORI INFECTION INCREASE THE LEVELS OF EXHALED NITRIC OXIDE?
(SagePub, 2013)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1721727X1301100129):

> It seems that H. pylori-associated gastritis is accompanied by an
>   increased level of exhaled **nitric oxide**...

According to [this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16721224), H. pylori was shown to produce hydrogen sulfide and **methyl mercaptan**...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting article. “Summary:
Bacteria that cause stomach ulcers and cancer could also be giving us bad breath, according to research published in the Journal of Medical Microbiology. For the first time, scientists have found Helicobacter pylori living in the mouths of people who are not showing signs of stomach disease.” (2008).

“"Although the presence of H. pylori in the mouth does not directly cause bad breath, it is associated with periodontal disease, which does cause bad breath," said Dr. Suzuki. "We now need to look into the relationship between H. pylori in the mouth and in the stomach. We hope to discover the role of the mouth in transmitting H. pylori stomach infections in the near future." https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/11/081123222846.htm

This would be H. Pylori infection of just the mouth, presumably, or at least not showing “signs” of stomach disease. Bottom line: this odor would be from gum disease caused or accelerated by H. Pylori.

So this is another route by which H. Pylori may contribute to bad breath.

No word on how it smells. Just bad.